# .push not working in constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

If I do:

```
function a(){
    a.list.push(this);
}
a.list = [];

new a();
```

`a.list` will be updated when `new a()` is called. But now,

```
function Spark(ctx){
    console.log("created", this);
    Spark.list.push[this];
}
Spark.list = [];
Spark.max = 100;
Spark.createSparks = function(ctx){
    if(this.list.length < this.max){
        new Spark(ctx);
    }
};

Spark.createSparks();
```

Here `Spark.list.push` is executed without any problem, but `Spark.list` remains empty. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not invoking the function.

Change

```
Spark.list.push[this]
```

to

```
Spark.list.push(this)
```

Comment: Oh wow. I took hours checking every line of my code but I never realized I typed in brackets rather than parenthesis. Thank you.